# ggplot2 graphic with several x variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need help for a R graphic issue with ggplot2.
Lets take an example :

```
date <- c("oct", "dec")

min.national <- c(17, 20)
min.international <- c(11, 12)
min.roaming <- c(5, 7)

mb.national <- c(115, 150)
mb.international <- c(72, 75)
mb.roaming <- c(30, 40)

df <- data.frame(min.national, min.international, min.roaming, mb.national, mb.international, mb.roaming)
```

What I want is to have two graphic one for the minutes and one for the megabytes sideline. And to get bars for the three variable (for the minutes in national, international and roaming for example) on the same graphic with ***fill = date*** ?
Is it clear for you ?
Thanks

Comment: What's unclear is what you have tried yourself.

Comment: sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: Excuse me but I tried and it's something difficult to do, I can show you my basic graph on R or this on excel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate there may be a language challenge here, and it sounds like you're just getting started with ggplot2 so not sure how to get started on this, so I hope you find this useful.

It makes sense to treat the minutes and mb separately; they're different units. So I'll just use the minutes as an example. What I understand you're trying to achieve is easy with the right approach and the tidyr library.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#first get your data in a data frame
min.df <- data.frame(national = min.national, international = min.international, roaming = min.roaming, month = date)
#now use the tidyr function to create a long data frame, you should recognize that this gives you a data structure readily suited to what you want to plot
min.df.long <- gather(min.df, "region", "minutes", 1:3)
ggplot(min.df.long) + geom_bar(aes(x = region, y = minutes, fill = month), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

If you want the months side by side, as I understand your question, then you could do:

```
ggplot(min.df.long) + geom_bar(aes(x = region, y = minutes, fill = factor(month, levels = c("oct", "dec"))), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + labs(fill = "month")
```

The key parameter is the position keyword, the rest is just to make it neater.
[image]

Comment: thank you very much, just one more question, how to make the bars side by side and by date ? I think it's easier to inderstand
(PS: I'm not new with ggplot but i have some problems to use tidyr and reshape ...)

Comment: See edited answer that, I think, does as you ask; it's a simple geom_bar position option.

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(date, min.national, min.international, min.roaming, mb.national, mb.international, mb.roaming)

df.stk <- tidyr::separate(melt(df), col="variable", into=c("min_byte", "type"), sep="\\.")

plt <- ggplot(df.stk, aes(type, value, fill = date)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        facet_grid(.~min_byte)
print(plt)
```

[image]

Comment: You are welcome, if this has answered your question, please mark this as answered.